# Custom block not displayed when added to local.xml in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, layout, block

I have a custom block (tabbed product info) which I want to display in the store's product view within the product view block itself. I correctly called the block in my view.phtml and use this code to add the block to my XML:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
```

The block is rendered when put into catalog.xml, but whenever I put it into my local.xml in form of

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
 <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
   <reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

it does not work. When I add the before or after tag (e.g. after="product.info.media") to the code snippet in local.xml, it is rendered but not within, but always before or after the whole product view block. In catalog.xml, I just placed it at between the other blocks and it worked fine.

When I copy the content of the whole product view section from catalog.xml into my local.xml it works, but the all the content (images, description, etc.) is displayed twice.

Is there any way to do this via local.xml? Maybe through setchild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the block to the **content** block. Update your `reference` *name* value to **product.info**. Based on your alias of **info_tabs**, as long as your template has

`echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs')`

you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about local.xml, are you talking about **/app/etc/local.xml** ? This file is a configuration file, not a layout update file. It's not intended to work like that.

If you are talking about another layout file (in app/design/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml) then you must add a **dependency** of the module which declared this layout update file to the module that declares original content of the page (in your case Mage_Catalog).

This is like that because, Magento *after* or *before* attributes compares only to already declared blocks, and I think your local.xml is parsed before the original catalog.xml

Let's assume that you have a module called StackOverflow_Local, that have in its config.xml (app/code/local/StackOverflow/Local/etc/config.xml) this declaration :

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <stackoverflow_local>
          <file>local.xml</file>
        </stackoverflow_local>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

Then you should have a declaration of your module in app/etc/modules/StackOverflow_Local.xml where you should find something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <StackOverflow_Local>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </StackOverflow_Local>
  </modules>
</config>
```

To add a dependancy (your module shouldn't work if Mage_Catalog is disabled/removed) transform your activation XML to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <StackOverflow_Local>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Catalog />
      </depends>
    </StackOverflow_Local>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: The assumption is that OP is talking about the local.xml layout file.